# How assert_select a string with a new line inside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I have this string inside my html code:

```
1\n          \n            word
```

I want to make an assert_select that ignores those new lines and spaces, so I have tried this:

```
assert_select ".myclass", /1.+word/
```

But it does not work:

```
1) Failure: 
test_new_line(NewLineControllerTest) [test/functional/new_line_controller_test.rb:23]:
</1.+word/> expected but was
<"1\n          \n            word">.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the multiline flag since there are multiple lines in that string.

```
assert_select ".myclass", /1.+word/m
```